# What is the best way to merge 2 tables with Active Record and Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

We need to allow users to customize their entities like products... so my intention was to have a product table and a custom_product table with just the information the users are allowed to change.

When a client goes to the product I want to merge the information, means I want to merge the two tables  - the custom overwrites the default Products table.

I know that in mysql there exists a ifnull(a.title, b.title) way but I was wondering if there is any nice and efficient way to solve this in Rails 4 with Active Record. Assume that the products and custom products table have just 2 columns, ID and TITLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can convert both objects to JSON and then handle their params as a hash, using the `merge` method:

```
class Product
end

class Customization
  belongs_to :product
end


a = Product.find(...)
b = a.customization

c = JSON(a.to_json).merge(JSON(b.to_json).reject!{|k,v| v.nil?})
```

Therefore `c` will contain all params from `Product` eventually overridden by those in `Customization` which are not nil.

If you still want to use a `Product` object with hybrid values (taken from `Customization`) you can try this:

```
a.attributes = a.attributes.merge(b.attributes.reject!{|k,v| v.nil?})
```

In this case `a` will still be a `Product` instance. I would recommend to keep the same attributes in both models when doing this.